# How to fix the sentence going outside from the box material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI..

I want to place the texts inside the box but when want to make responsive ,the texts are going outside of thr box.

Note : I have already tried other solutions of stackover flow like word-wrap, max-width,min-width but did not work.

[image]

code is,

```
<Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                        <Box color={'rgb(24, 119, 242)'}><FacebookIcon /></Box>
                                        <Box
                                            sx={{
                                                '&:hover': {
                                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                                    textDecoration: 'underline',
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Link href="#" underline="none">
                                                https://www.facebook.com/caitlyn.kerluke
                                            </Link>
                                        </Box>
                                    </Stack>
                                    <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                        <Box color={'rgb(224, 45, 105)'}><InstagramIcon /></Box>
                                        <Box
                                            sx={{
                                                '&:hover': {
                                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                                    textDecoration: 'underline',
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Link href="#" underline="none">
                                                https://www.instagram.com/caitlyn.kerluke
                                            </Link>
                                        </Box>
                                    </Stack>
                                    <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                        <Box color={'rgb(0, 126, 187)'}><LinkedInIcon /></Box>
                                        <Box
                                            sx={{
                                                '&:hover': {
                                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                                    textDecoration: 'underline',
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Link href="#" underline="none">
                                                https://www.linkedin.com/in/caitlyn.kerluke
                                            </Link>
                                        </Box>
                                    </Stack>
                                    <Stack direction={'row'} spacing={2}>
                                        <Box color={'rgb(0, 170, 236)'}><TwitterIcon /></Box>
                                        <Box
                                            sx={{
                                                '&:hover': {
                                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                                    textDecoration: 'underline',
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Link href="#" underline="none">
                                                https://www.twitter.com/caitlyn.kerluke
                                            </Link>
                                        </Box>
                                    </Stack>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Text overflow` css property:

```
 <Box
      sx={{
        "&:hover": {
          cursor: "pointer",
          textDecoration: "underline"
        },
        overflow: "hidden",
        textOverflow: "ellipsis"
      }}
    >
      <Link href="#" underline="none">
        https://www.facebook.com/caitlyn.kerluke
      </Link>
    </Box>
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-gauss-09yww7?file=/src/App.js

You can read more about it on official doc: https://mui.com/system/display/#text-overflow

Comment: have already tried this @DreamBold but not working

Comment: added:-   https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-flower-u0hkq6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yes its working but ,is there any other way to show the full text without using textOverflow options like I dont want scroll.

Comment: I mean,I don't want  to hide the texts

Comment: yes no issue...

Comment: do you have any Idea how to do this

Comment: https://prnt.sc/EoLnictuv3tj ,I need this design,like no text should cut or eclipse....

Comment: Have a look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-gauss-09yww7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yes,@DreamBold I checked that Its working perfectly...and thanks for you time and support